# How can I get rid of Reference error using music-metadata in electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to use music-metadata but keep getting the following error. I already checked the package.json file and deleted the nodes_modules folder several times.

[image]

```js
const $ = require('jquery');
const mm = require('music-metadata');

function chooseMusic() {
  $('input').click();
}

function musicSelected() {
  const files = $('input').get(0).files;
  console.log(files);

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const {path} = files[i];
    mm.parseFile(path).then((metadata) => {
      console.log(metadata.common.title);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: did you reenable node integration or did you provide `require` on another way (like in a preload script)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an older version of music-metadata. I reinstalled it with the newest version and the error disappeared.